# Reading value .properties file ( java )

Tags: java

I have java class in which a `ResourceBundle` is created:

```
protected static ResourceBundle bundle = ResourceBundle.getBundle("application");
```

And I have an *application.properties* file. So I think the bundle is trying to open this *application.properties*.

From the java class the bundle is trying to get a value:

```
bundle.getString("attachment_path_img")
```

But when I go in *application.properties* file I get a entry with

```
attachment_path_img = <ATTACHMENT_PATH_IMG>
```

What kind of definition is this ? How is the value for `<ATTACHMENT_PATH_IMG>` taken ? Where should I look for it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If your *application.properties* contains a line with `attachment_path_img = <ATTACHMENT_PATH_IMG>` and if `bundle.getString("attachment_path_img")` returns `<ATTACHMENT_PATH_IMG>` then everything works fine.

If you don't want to have a `<ATTACHMENT_PATH_IMG>` but a real value, then you have to change the *application.properties*.

**Note** that `ResourceBundle` is for locale specific values:

> When your program needs a locale-specific resource, a String for example, your program can load it from the resource bundle that is appropriate for the current user's locale
>
> -- https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ResourceBundle.html

Usually the application configuration is read by the [`Properties`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html) class (or more powerful implementations)

Comment: Is there a way that can see actual path like Folder1/Folder2/.. for each locale.I have to debug this application, its not my code actually..

Comment: The structure of a resource folder is standard and describe into the `ResourceBundle` doc. The location is relative to the classpath, so if you have a `new ResourceBundle("application.properties")` your file will be in your root source folder.

Answer (score 0):

1: You don't need ResourceBundle for reading a plain properties file. (http://www.avajava.com/tutorials/lessons/how-do-i-read-a-properties-file.html) ResourceBundle is intended for multiple localized property files.

2: There is no placeholder mechanism built into property files. It is usually introduced by framework working on top of these files like Spring.